# How can I run javascript code when someone is loading my npm package?

Tags: node.js, function, logging, global

I'm developing an npm package having multiple files.

Is there a way to run the same javascript code when someone is using my npm package via `require` or `import`?

My npm packages can be loaded like

```
const alik = require('alik')
```

or

```
const alikHelper = require('alik/helpers/alik-helper')
```

or

```
import alik from "alik";
```

Comment: Not entirely sure there is a more elegant way than the traditional way of having a separate file containing your function that is being reused and importing it in each file it is needed. However, I did find [this article](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/the-process-module/) about the global process module in NodeJS. The article is fairly outdated so not sure it would be helpful but may be worth a look to see if theres anything in there that could help you!